# Full screen Here Map has black bar at the bottom

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here Maps JS API within a Vue application.  When toggling into full screen mode I'm dynamically setting the height of the container within which the Here Map is rendered. (100vh and 100vw)
I also have an event listener registered for the map so that it can respond to the resize event:

```
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    this.map.getViewPort().resize();
  });
```

The map does take up the entire page as I can see the logo at the bottom of the screen but there's a black bar with no map details along the bottom:

[image: Black bar at bottom]

What could be causing this?

Comment: are you able to reproduce the same issue without using Vue application, say in a simple html page?

Comment: Looks like this was to do with the vue-fullscreen component that was being used.  Calling the fullscreen API directly doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: We suggest you to add Vue tag to your question so that experts in Vue will be able to provide you an appropriate answer.

Comment: Don't worry, I've gone ahead and implemented without reliance on the 3rd party so that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was to do with the vue-fullscreen component that was being used. Calling the fullscreen API directly doesn't have the same problem so we've removed the reliance on the 3rd party and use the browser API in our own components using:

```
this.$refs.map.requestFullscreen(); // $refs allows the retrieval of an element based on a ref attribute on the element
```

and

```
document.exitFullscreen();
```